# Botframework Composer chatbot continues where it left off

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I developed a chatbot with Bot Framework Composer. I start the chatbot with iframe and perform the transactions. Then, when I log back in with iframe, the chatbot continues where it left off. I want it to start over at every boot. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code you already have?

Comment: A bot that I created as a flowchart on Composer. Which code should I share?

Comment: Ok, the screenshot may help us to understand the issue.

Comment: I added the introduction of the bot.

Comment: You need to clean the history before turning to the start point.

Comment: Yes, I clear all variables at the end of the bot. But when I add it to my website with any iframe, the bot continues where it left off.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'iframe' and 'log back in'? I'm assuming you are using Web Chat channel, but are you using using the embedded version (`<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/DMVBasicBot?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'  style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>`) or have you created an iframe that then references the ['full' webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) in that iframe? Also, what is actually getting logged into?